# Get a list of computer science.edu websites using google

Tags: search, web, web-crawler, design-patterns

Hey I was wondering if there was a specific query that I could enter into google that would result in google giving me a list of the computer science home pages of all the universities with a '.edu' address.

I require this because I have to crawl these websites to accumulate lecture notes for courses.

Hence any help would be much appreciated.

Or if anyone knows of any index that is maintained with a list of urls of all such university computer science websites that would do as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
site:.edu computer science
```

Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:.edu%20computer%20science

Comment: perfect I was planning to do www.cs.?.edu which is not quite as clean. Thanks so much this would work perfectly.